# Reasons for erratic behaviour loading constants from env->config->blade in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am running Laravel Framework 5.8.37 (Haven't had time to upgrade yet...)

I have Sstripe as a payment solution in my laravel app. After some refactoring I am about to re-implement my payment stuff from Stripe.

I keep all my keys and stuff in the .env.  like:

```
STRIPE_PUB_KEY= pk_test_MyKeYs
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY= sk_test_MyKeYs
STRIPE_END_POINT_SECRET = whsec_MyKeYs
```

In the app.config I define them:

```
'stripe_pub_key' => env('STRIPE_PUB_KEY'),
'stripe_secret_key' => env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'),
'stripe_end_point_secret' => env('STRIPE_END_POINT_SECRET')
```

Then from my code I call:

```
var stripe = Stripe("{{ config('app.stripe_pub_key') }}");
```

Everything SHOLD work. But what happens? I get the error:

```
Uncaught IntegrationError: Please call Stripe() with your publishable key. You used an empty string.
```

The call to the config returns empty string! Strange, well it will get worse. To be able to test better I've just added this to my blade:

```
<h1>My response:{{ config('app.stripe_pub_key') }}</h1>
```

It does indeed return empty string. Now to the real strangeness. If I change to:

```
<h1>My response:{{ config('app.stripe_secret_key') }}</h1>
```

... just to test. It returns the secret key!!!  - It also works with the end point secret. It seems to just be the pub_key that does not work... Also if I make a random new one it does not seem to work...

What can this be?

Comment: You probably need to recache your config using `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:cache`. Also, remove the spaces in your env file are the `=`.

Comment:  Please add as answer and I will mark as correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to recache your config using `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:cache`.

Also, remove the spaces in your env file are the `=`.